# How to prevent the page from scrolling when scrolling inside a scroll box and hitting bottom of scroll box

Tags: firefox, scrolling, scroll-wheel

Firefox has this "feature" that scrolls the entire page once I hit the bottom of a scroll box (either iframe or one created using the css overflow property).

This only happen when I scroll using the scroll-wheel. When I scroll using the arrow keys, once I hit the bottom of the scroll box nothing will happen.

I find the scroll-wheel behaviour irritating. Can I configure Firefox so the scroll-wheel inside scroll boxes behave like the arrow keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, that behaviour seems to be a ["feature"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188698) and not a bug.